# Thread-safe TBB scalable allocator

Tags: c++, thread-safety, tbb

Recently I switched from system memory management (malloc/free) to Intel's TBB scalable allocator. The problem is I cannot find any info if it's thread-safe. Whole TBB is built around threads, so it would seem logical, but without concrete evidence, I do not want to assume such things. Yet, I do not want to make any unnecessary synchronization either. Does anyone have some info on this?

Comment: It is definitely thread-safe. Must be in the documentation somewhere.

Comment: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/reference/memory_allocation/scalable_allocator_cls/c_interface_to_scalable_allocator.htm - this is all the documentation available. Are you absolutely sure about it being thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the manual you linked:

> Unless otherwise stated, the thread safety rules for the library are
>   as follows:
>
> Two threads can invoke a method or function concurrently on different
>   objects, but not the same object. It is unsafe for two threads to
>   invoke concurrently methods or functions on the same object.
>   Descriptions of the classes note departures from this convention. For
>   example, the concurrent containers are more liberal. By their nature,
>   they do permit some concurrent operations on the same container
>   object.

With the scalable allocator this means two threads cannot free the same memory at the same time, which should not be surprising.

Comment: This quote is somewhat ambiguous. Scalable allocator C API doesn't explicitly involve any objects/structs being passed around, yet may do so internally with or without synchronization. Therefore it's unclear (at least to me) if using it in different threads is safe or should every call be wrapped in a mutex lock.

Comment: Overcomplicating the API: the alloc function has no objects, the free function has one.

Comment: After some digging, I found http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/12/19/scalable-memory-pools-community-preview-feature with info about thread-safety and it looks to be consistent with what you say. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Then this source [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~johnmc/comp522/lecture-notes/COMP522-2012-Lecture9-TBB.pdf) sounds more straight (see page "TBB Scalable Allocator")-

> Each thread has its own private heap
>
> – Size-segregated bins improve locality
>   – Private heaps reduce
>   synchronization overhead  and false sharing

Update: And from [here](http://scott.wolchok.org/498/lecture17)-

> TBB provides a scalable allocator with per-thread pools.
>          It *may* still have false sharing.
>
> ```
>    example: false sharing could matter in pipelining.
>
>    TBB also provides a cache-aligned allocator, which guarantees
>    that any two things you've allocated will never experience
>    false sharing. The downside is that it has larger memory
>    pressure. This is accomplished by making the minimum allocation
>    N cache lines, where N is a small integer.
>
>    In the book, the conventional wisdom is to start with the
>    scalable allocator and see if switching to the cache-aligned
>    allocator speeds things up.
> ```

But false-sharing is about slowdown not thread-safety.